# Как сделать автокоррекцию изображения(Яркость\Контрастность) для изображения Android Opencv/ColorMatrixFilter

Tags: android, opencv, xamarin, фильтры

Я использую **OpenCV** для андроида.
Хотелось бы узнать,как можно сделать **автокоррекцию изображения** (контраст\яркость) посредством библиотеки **OpenCV** или же это можно сделать нативном образом?(через **ColorMatrixFilter** от Android'a).

Пытался нагуглить,но так и не нашел вменяего туториала\примера по данной теме.
Как можно это сделать?
Благодарю!

Answer (score 3):

Несмотря на то, что алгоритмов восстановления неравномерно освещённых изображений разработано множество, OpenCV на сегодняшний день не предоставляет чего-то такого готового из коробки. Тем не менее в сети имеется множество примеров реализации и как раз с использованием OpenCV.

Чаще всего встречаются алгоритмы на основе Retinex (немного связанной теории на русской вики: [Цветопостоянство](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)), но хотелось бы выделить сайт, если не ошибаюсь, хорватских разработчиков - ["Image Processing Group"](http://www.fer.unizg.hr/ipg). На нём в свободном доступе представлены не только исходники (С++ / OpenCV, лицензия GNU GPL), но даже и [инструмент](http://fly.srk.fer.hr/~nbanic/f/), позволяющий воочию оценить результаты работы алгоритмов непосредственно в браузере.

[image: До обработки]
[image: После обработки]

Comment: можно ссылочку на исходники?(а то что то я не нахожу на сайте)

Comment: @VetaLio, смотрите в разделе меню Resources -> Color constancy